# How to filter a value from dictionary, this dictionary contains more than 1 value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to do this, where i key in the value of 10 and it will filter out the values have more than 10 and give the result:

'b':['sam',20], 'c':['rose',30], 'd':['mary',40], 'e':['jon',50]

Below is the code I am trying:

```
h = int(input("Enter Value: "))
ini_dict = {'a':['abc',10], 'b':['sam',20], 'c':['rose',30], 'd':['mary',40], 'e':['jon',50]} 
 # printing initial dictionary
print ("initial lists", str(ini_dict))` 
result = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1]>h, ini_dict.items())) 
result = dict(result)  
print("resultant dictionary : ", str(result))
```

I encountered this error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'" . 
Beside this, I have tried to modify:

result = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1]>h, ini_dict.items())) into

this result = dict(filter(lambda x,y:x,y[1]>h, ini_dict.items()))  and encounter error y undefined.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue here: when you type `x[1]` you are selecting the entirety of the list in each element in the dictionary. in order to access the index that you require INSIDE the list, you should try `x[1][1]`. so modifying the code like I said:

```
h = int(input("Enter Value: "))
ini_dict = {'a':['abc',10], 'b':['sam',20], 'c':['rose',30], 'd':['mary',40], 'e':['jon',50]}
 # printing initial dictionary
print ("initial lists", str(ini_dict))
result = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1][1]>h, ini_dict.items()))
result = dict(result)
print("resultant dictionary : ", str(result))
```

The output:

```
Enter Value: 10
initial lists {'a': ['abc', 10], 'b': ['sam', 20], 'c': ['rose', 30], 'd': ['mary', 40], 'e': ['jon', 50]}
resultant dictionary :  {'b': ['sam', 20], 'c': ['rose', 30], 'd': ['mary', 40], 'e': ['jon', 50]}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! really appreciated. The x[1][1] refers to entire list with going inside ['abc',10] etc.. start as 1? Is this by default to be 1? I tried x[1][2] and found out list out of range index error.

Comment: you're welcome. No `x[1]` in itself refers to for example `['abc', 10]` (the second index of a certain element in the dictionary). so now we have the second element (a list) in hand with `x[1]`. now we wanna access something INSIDE that element. first index inside the list is a string for example "sam" which can be accessed with ` x[1][0] ` . second element, the integer, can be accessed by  ` x[1][1] ` . and you get an error with  ` x[1][2] ` the lists in the elements in your dictionary, only have two values!! if they have a third value, then  ` x[1][2] ` would have worked.

Comment: python starts at 0 when indexing. so in this example: `x[1][0]` will refer to 'abc' and  `x[1][1]` will refer to 10

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Now i understand it better.